# amcharts5 - format values in tooltips with a custom function

Tags: javascript, graph, amcharts, amcharts5

I'm using amcharts5 to represent some data. At a certain point I have a series where I want to display the tooltip differently from the original value.

Let's say for example my chart is something like this:

```
var series2 = chart.series.push(
  am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
    name: "Expenses",
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    valueYField: "expenses",
    categoryXField: "year",
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
      pointerOrientation: "horizontal",
      labelText: "{name} in {categoryX}: {valueY} {info}"
    })
  })
);
```

I would like to setup things like:

```
labelText: "{name}: {Math.abs(valueY)} $"
```

or

```
labelText: "{name}: {2*valueY} $"
```

or

```
labelText: "{name}: {customFunction(valueY)} $"
```

but none of these works.

https://jsfiddle.net/2eb59g07/

I've read the documentation but I'm confused, between amcharts4 and 5 things changed a bit and while one documentation talks about number formatter the other talks about formatter as custom function. But there's no available clear examples of how this thing is implemented in the code of the v5 version.

Comment: Can you please replicate this example so that we can debug it and see the exact value??

Comment: @mandy8055 done, now it can be tested.

Comment: @mandy8055 done

Comment: did you try the updated solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting called **[`tooltipText`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/common-elements/tooltips/#Common_elements)** using which you can format the tooltip text using a string template that can include placeholders for dynamic values.

Below the the `tooltipText` property is set to a string template that includes placeholders for the series name and the `valueY` field, which represents the y-value of each data point.

```js
var series2 = chart.series.push(
  am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
    name: "Expenses",
    xAxis: xAxis,
    yAxis: yAxis,
    valueYField: "expenses",
    categoryXField: "year",
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
      pointerOrientation: "horizontal",
      formatter: function (value, info) {
        return Math.abs(value) + " $";
      }
    }),
    tooltipText: "{name}: {valueY}"
  })
);
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g6dwmapt/1/)***

**EDIT:**

As per your new requirement, you can just add **[`adapters`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/settings/adapters/)** on `labelText` to get it done. Something like below:

```js
series2.get("tooltip").label.adapters.add("text", function(text, target) {
    text = "";
    var tooltipDataItem = series2?.get("tooltipDataItem");
    text += series2?.get("name") + " : $" + customFun(tooltipDataItem?.get("valueY")); // Edit the text as per requirement.
    return text
  });
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g6dwmapt/47/)***

Comment: Oh, a second I tried it and just realized that I haven't put in the example any negative data, however it doesn't seems to work. It just stops lags a bit more and return the original value (for example I can't see the dollar sign).

Comment: Hmmm...this should be pretty easy I surmise. I have edited my answer. Please have a look.